# Function types declarations in Mathematica

Tags: function, types, wolfram-mathematica

I have bumped into this problem several times on the type of input data declarations mathematica understands for functions.

It Seems Mathematica understands the following types declarations:
_Integer,
_List,
_?MatrixQ,
_?VectorQ

However: _Real,_Complex declarations for instance cause the function sometimes not to compute. Any idea why?

What's the general rule here?

Comment: It is not clean what is being asked.  Please give example code and/or further explanation.

Comment: @ Mr. Wizard: I've silghtly edited, but I think the question is clear enough and the answers provided below have helped address the problem I had. For instance I did not understand why when inputting an integer number with Real type restriction, it would return false.  Anyway the answers below really help me get to the bottom of this issue and usefully expand beyond...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When you do something like `f[x_]:=Sin[x]`, what you are doing is defining a pattern replacement rule. If you instead say `f[x_smth]:=5` (if you try both, do `Clear[f]` before the second example), you are really saying "wherever you see `f[x]`, check if the head of `x` is `smth` and, if it is, replace by 5". Try, for instance,

```
Clear[f]
f[x_smth]:=5
f[5]
f[smth[5]]
```

So, to answer your question, the rule is that in `f[x_hd]:=1;`, `hd` can be anything and is matched to the head of x.

One can also have more complicated definitions, such as `f[x_] := Sin[x] /; x > 12`, which will match if x>12 (of course this can be made arbitrarily complicated).

Edit: I forgot about the Real part. You can certainly define `Clear[f];f[x_Real]=Sin[x]` and it works for eg f[12.]. But you have to keep in mind that, while `Head[12.]` is `Real`, `Head[12]` is `Integer`, so that your definition won't match.

Answer (score 6):

Just a quick note since no one else has mentioned it. You can pattern match for multiple `Head`s - and this is quicker than using the conditional matching of `?` or `/;`.

```
f[x:(_Integer|_Real)] := True (* function definition goes here *)
```

For simple functions acting on Real or Integer arguments, it runs in about 75% of the time as the similar definition

```
g[x_] /; Element[x, Reals] := True (* function definition goes here *)
```

(which as WReach pointed out, runs in 75% of the time
as  `g[x_?(Element[#, Reals]&)] := True`).

The advantage of the latter form is that it works with Symbolic constants such as `Pi` - although if you want a purely numeric function, this can be fixed in the former form with the use of `N`.

Comment: Matching for multiple heads like this is very fragile.  It's so easy to forget about one type of expression, as you forgot about `Rational` here, or something like `Sqrt[2]` (not only `Pi`).  If you need to check if the expression is numeric only (and not whether it has an imaginary part), `x_?NumericQ` is best.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I originally thought about `Rational`, because I checked that it doesn't include complex rationals, then I forgot to include it! And yeah... all sorts of numeric functions acting on `Reals` or `Rationals` will break the head checking. So you're right, `NumericQ` combined with an optional check to see if it's in the `Reals` is probably best / the most robust.

Answer (score 4):

The most likely problem is the input your using to test the the functions.  For instance,

```
f[x_Complex]:= Conjugate[x]
f[x + I y]
f[3 + I 4]
```

returns

```
f[x + I y]
3 - I 4
```

The reason the second one works while the first one doesn't is revealed when looking at their `FullForm`s

```
x + I y // FullForm == Plus[x, Times[ Complex[0,1], y]]
3 + I 4 // FullForm == Complex[3,4]
```

Internally, Mathematica transforms `3 + I 4` into a `Complex` object because each of the terms is numeric, but `x + I y` does not get the same treatment as `x` and `y` are `Symbols`.  Similarly, if we define

```
g[x_Real] := -x
```

and using them

```
g[ 5 ]  == g[ 5 ]
g[ 5. ] == -5.
```

The key here is that `5` is an `Integer` which is not recognized as a subset of `Real`, but by adding the decimal point it becomes `Real`.

As [acl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605867/function-types-declarations-in-mathematica/5606149#5606149) pointed out, the pattern `_Something` means match to anything with `Head === Something`, and both the `_Real` and `_Complex` cases are very restrictive in what is given those `Head`s.

Comment: Why doesn't mma recognize `Integer` as a subset of `Real` when it is perfectly valid mathematically?

Comment: @RM, I think its because of how the pattern matching mechanism works, in that it only looks at the `Head` of the expression. So, when you type `5` vs. `5.` you get an `Integer` expression vs. a `Real` expression. Then the pattern matcher only sees that the heads don't match. If you want to match both use `_?NumericQ`. You run across this problem all the time when matching patterns when an internal alters the expression just enough to no longer match. For me, the most infamous is collecting the imaginary part of a complex expression ...

Comment: @RM, continuing ... The easiest method I've found is to transform it slightly via `Complex[a_,b_]:> a + q b`, apply `Sqrt[-1]` power rules to `q`, `Collect[<expr>,q]`, and convert back via `q -> I`. Not simple, but effective.

Comment: @R. M. Head matching, and pattern matching in general, have no notion of mathematical validity -- the only concern is the structural form of expressions.  Notions of mathematical validity need to be programmed explicitly.  For example, if one wanted a function that applied to any real number in the mathematical sense, one would write `f[x_ /; x \[Element] Reals] := ...`.

Comment: @WReach, or `f[x_?(Element[#, Reals]&)]` is equally valid. I wonder which runs faster?

Comment: @rcollyer, @Wreach: thanks for the explanation! I remember seeing the `I->q` trick (perhaps it was your comment on a post on collecting expressions) and that's really cool.

Comment: @rcollyer: Just for laughs I tried a microbenchmark: `Timing[Do[f[10], {10000000}]]` for both variants.  `/;` ran in 75% of the time required by `?`.  I wouldn't read too much into this result.  In Mathematica, expressiveness and clarity are generally more important than performance.  I would just go ahead and write whichever form was clearest in the context.  There is also personal preference at work -- I happen to use '/;' a lot.  YMMV.  When performance is a big deal, then one is likely to look for a different algorithm or, failing that, using `Compile` or symbolic C or something.

Comment: @RM, it probably was as I've posted it here before. not that I can remember where ...

Comment: @WReach: That's interesting. I always assumed that the timing would be the otherway around. That the pure function form applied to the single pattern would be faster than the test on the local variable...

Comment: @WReach The reason probably is that `FullForm` of `Condition` is substantially simpler that `FullForm` of `PatternTest` with `Function`: `f[x_ /; x \[Element] Reals] // FullForm` and
`f[x_?(Element[#, Reals] &)] // FullForm`. Without `Function` `PatternTest` is slightly faster: `ClearAll[f];
f[x_?NumericQ] := x;
Timing[Do[f[10], {20000000}]]` and `ClearAll[f];
f[x_ /; NumericQ[x]] := x;
Timing[Do[f[10], {20000000}]]`. This confirm your insight that we should write whichever form is clearest in the context.